# jQuery function firing multiple times on scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a function when the user has scrolled 100px past the top of the site footer, the function is to load some additional page content. So I have the following script:

```
$(window).on(‘scroll’, function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(‘#footer’).height() – 100) {
load_posts();
}
});
```

However, the function is running multiple times, and using console.log I have discovered that the load_posts() function is actually running once for every pixel passed that 100px, i.e. if I scroll 105px in the footer it loads 5 times, so additional content is loaded 5 times.

How do I get the function only to load once? So that the user can see the new content then continue to scroll down to load the next further content? Perhaps a timeout before it loads, so that the first lot of additional content has time to load before it runs a second time and therefore the user is no longer in the footer?

Comment: You can use `once`, `on` and `off`, variables for saving the status that you have already loaded, or the javascript Intersection Observer API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working with the following:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop()+$(window).height() > $('footer').offset().top){
        if(!($loader.hasClass('post_loading_loader') || $loader.hasClass('post_no_more_posts'))){
                load_posts();
        }
    }
});
```

Taken from here: https://silvawebdesigns.com/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

There is a small trick you can use for this problem: it works on my machine.

Use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of your html.

Comment: It's a given that a web page would have a doctype at the top.